# HTML template in Typo3

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm learning **Typo3** and wanted to create my own website. I have found that it's very difficult to work with **Typo Script**.

Is there an easy way to integrate an example HTML5 template in **Typo3**? I'm using the latest version of **Typo3** (6.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option to learn this easy way is http://typo3buddy.com/ by Ronald Eijkman. Great place to start, and I would chose Fluid templating instead TemplaVoila...

Answer (score 0):

TypoScript is must-know technology, if you wan't to use TYPO3...

You can use [`TemplaVoila`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/templavoila) extension as *other* templating engine, anyway it also has it's requirements (*learning curve*)